# Getting different output when casting between int and int64 in Go; is it due to processor architecture?

Tags: go, casting, int, int64

A small part of an application I'm using to test some expected behavior is giving different output, depending on what processor I run it on. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
   for b := 0; b < intCounter; b++ {

            //int64Random = rand.Int63()
            int64Random = int64(rand.Int())

//CHECKING FOR SANITY
fmt.Println("int64Random is " + strconv.FormatInt(int64Random, 10))

            slcTestNums = append(slcTestNums, int64Random)
    }
```

When I run this on my Mac (amd64, darwin) I get output like:

```
int64Random is 2991558990735723489
int64Random is 7893058381743103687
int64Random is 7672635040537837613
int64Random is 1557718564618710869
int64Random is 2107352926413218802
```

When I run this on a Pi (arm, linux) I get output like:

```
int64Random is 1251459732
int64Random is 1316852782
int64Random is 971786136
int64Random is 1359359453
int64Random is 729066469
```

If on the Pi I change the int64Random to = rand.Int63() and recompile, I get output like:

```
int64Random is 7160249008355881289
int64Random is 7184347289772016444
int64Random is 9201664581141930074
int64Random is 917219239600463359
int64Random is 6015348270214295654
```

...which more closely matches what the Mac is getting. Is this because of something that is changed at runtime due to the processor architecture? Why is `int64(rand.Int())` generating int64-ranged numbers instead of keeping an int-ranged number, but changing the type for the variable it's being stored in? Am I missing the Go documentation that mentions this behavior?

Comment: If you want 32 bits use `int32` (and `rand.Int31`); if you want 64 bits use `int64` (and `rand.Int63`); if you want to use either 32 or 64 bits as "appropriate" for your architecture then use `int` (and `rand.Int`). Although `int` is *like* either `int32` or `int64` it is always a distinct type from both. With that it should be obvious why `int64(rand.Int())` returns 32 (actually 31 bit) values on a arch where int is 32 bit.

Comment: … and also why your "int64Random is" output is a lie if you actually call `rand.Int` instead of `rand.Int63`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://golang.org/doc/go1.1

> The language allows the implementation to choose whether the int type
>   and uint types are 32 or 64 bits. Previous Go implementations made int
>   and uint 32 bits on all systems. Both the gc and gccgo implementations
>   now make int and uint 64 bits on 64-bit platforms such as AMD64/x86-64

rand.Int() returns int. On amd64 it will be 64 bits, on ARM it will be 32 bits